# divide a categorized list into parts in django template

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Event_Category(models.Model):
    event=models.ForeignKey(Event,related_name='event_category')
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='events')
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

in the view:

```
magazie_cats=Event_Category.objects.filter(event=instance).order_by('category').distinct()
return render_to_response('CompanyHub/Company/index.html', {'magazie_cats':magazie_cats},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in the template:

```
{% regroup magazie_cats by category as service_list %}
```

I want to divide this categorized list into 3 parts and iterate over it. I tried to access each category by variable indexes:

```
    {% for i in range(0,3) %}
       {% for item in service_list.i.list %}
           {{item.event.title}}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for i in range(3,6) %}
       {% for item in service_list.i.list %}
           {{item.event.title}}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for i in range(6,9) %}
       {% for item in service_list.i.list %}
           {{item.event.title}}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**NOTE:** the range for each loop is calculated by some custom filters based on service_list length . I didn't include the complete code to avoid complexity.

The problem is that the list variable index doesn't work and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) filter:

```
{% regroup magazie_cats by category as service_list %}

{% for cat in service_list|slice:":3" %}
    {% for item in cat.list %}
        {{item.event.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for cat in service_list|slice:"3:6" %}
    {% for item in cat.list %}
        {{item.event.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for cat in service_list|slice:"6:9" %}
    {% for item in cat.list %}
        {{item.event.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I talked about slice a categorized list,not about grouper !

Comment: \I was mentioning the grouper separately (not as the answer). Now I understand what you're looking for, though. Just a moment.